# No way to make a specific cronjob work

Tags: cron

I installed nginxcp on my server and they recommend to add the following cron:

```
0 */1 * * * /usr/sbin/tmpwatch -am 1 /tmp/nginx_client
```

I already added it to var/spool/cron and restarted crond service, but it just doesnt work.

From time to time, I need to run the command `/usr/sbin/tmpwatch -am 1 /tmp/nginx_client` on ssh to clear the tmp.

Any idea, why the command is not running from the crontab?

Comment: output of crontab -l  ?

Comment: OS?  If GNU/Linux, distro?

Comment: What do you mean by "added it to `/var/spool...`? `crontab -e` handles this for you, don't do it manually.

Comment: Just to be clear, that cron will run every 1 hour at 00 minutes on the hour.  So make sure you're waiting until at least then to verify whether it's working or not.  Secondly, you can probably change it `0 * * * *` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Crontab is the program used to install, deinstall or list the tables used to drive the cron daemon in Cron.
Edit the crontab file to be use as below:

```
#crontab -e
```

and then insert above rule that will run after every one hour. then restart crond.